# Help me this proof! Related to RSA public key cryptosystem

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

Basically it is similar to the RSA algorithm.

> Let p and q be distince primes and let e and d be the integers
>   satisfying 
>  $de≡1$ (mod (p-1)(q-1)).
>
> Suppose further that c is an integer with gcd(c,pq)>1.
>
> Prove that $x≡c^d$ (mod pq) is a solution to the congruence $x^e≡c$
>   (mod pq).

I have done with when gcd(c,pq)=1 which I found pretty easy.
But for when gcd(c,pq)>1, c and pq has same factor. So, $p$ or $q$ or $pq$ is a divisor of c.

And then I am stuck with it.

What is the next step of the proof?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're trying to show $c^{de}\equiv c\pmod{pq}$. It suffices to show $c^{de}\equiv c\pmod p$ and $c^{de}\equiv c\pmod q$. Consider two cases for the first of these, depending on whether or not $c$ is a multiple of $p$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Case 1: Let gcd(c,pq)=p. <br> By Euler's Theorem, for any integer x, $x^\phi(m)≡1$ (mod m).
So, whether c is a multiple of p or not, $(c^d)^e≡c^de≡c^(\phi(pq)k+1)≡c$ (mod pq), where k is an integer.

Comment: Case 2: Let gcd(c,pq)=q. By symmetry, $(c^d)^e≡c^(de)≡c^(\phi(pq)k+1)≡c$ (mod pq), where k is an integer.

Comment: Case 3: Let gcd(c,pq)=pq. Then c≡0 (mod pq). $0^x≡0$ (mod pq) where x is any interger. 


Am I on the right track?

Comment: Hard to read what you've written...if you want $c^{de}$, you have to go c^{de}...but I don't see how you justify $c^{\phi(pq)k+1}\equiv c\pmod{pq}$. Oh, wait: $(c^{\phi(pq)})^kc$. Looks OK.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you with bad notations like the using $c^(de)$ instead of $c^{de}$